# Page accessible once a message is sent

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-mail

I have a contact form and I created a page to show when the message is sent but I want this page to be accessible only when the message is sent. Is it possible?

Here are lines from the ContactFormController

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required',

    ]);

    Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ContactFormMail($data));

    return redirect('contact.recieved');
}
```

Because when I go to the contact.recieved page it opens, I want it to open only if the message is sent.

Here are lines form the web.php file

```
Route::get('contact', 'ContactFormController@create')->name('contact.create');
Route::post('contact', 'ContactFormController@store')->name('contact.store');
Route::view('message-recieved', 'contact.recieved');
```

Here is the contact.recieved page

```
<body style="background: lightgrey;">
<div class="centered text-success ">
    <h1>Message Recieved! :)</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>Thank you for your message. I'll be in touch.</p>
</div>
<div class="p-4">
    <a class="a-links p-2 border border-success rounded-sm" href="{{url('/')}}">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left text-success"> <span> Go Back</span></i>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Before doing the redirect() you can store a session variable which indicate that the form is filled. Then on the received page you can do if(!isset(...)) against this variable and redirect back.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you can use **try catch** block as follows :

```
public function store()
{
    $data = request()->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'message' => 'required',
    ]);

    try { 

      Mail::to('test@test.com')->send(new ContactFormMail($data));

    } catch (\Swift_TransportException $e){
        return "Cant send email"; // Return this, if not send
    }
    return redirect('contact.recieved'); // Return this, if send successfully
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I added the following code to the contact.recieved page and it worked.

```
@if (session()->has('message'))

<body style="background: lightgrey;">
<div class="centered text-success ">
    <h1>Message Recieved! :)</h1>
    <hr>
    <p>{{ session()->get('message')}} </p>
</div>
<div class="p-4">
    <a class="a-links p-2 border border-success rounded-sm" href="{{url('/')}}">
        <i class="fa fa-angle-left text-success"> <span> Go Back</span></i>
    </a>
</div>
</body>
@else
<body class="notFound">
    <div class="flex-center position-ref full-height">
        <div class="code not-found text-capitalize">404</div>

        <div class="message not-found text-capitalize" style="padding: 10px;">Not `Found</div>`
    </div>
</body>
@endif
```